# What are the basic tips and trics forASP.Net/Web programming and common mistakes a programmer makes?

Tags: asp.net

What should a web programmer keep in his mind while creating a web application ?

What should he keep in his mind i.e. using Session variables, Global.asax file etc.

Please share your experiences .

Comment: Please make this a community wiki.

Comment: What is community wiki , Daniel ?

Comment: I agree, this question is too vague to provide a definitive answer to

Comment: @Praveen ASP.Net/WebProgramming?

Comment: Is there something wrong in this question ?
New programmers makes so many common mistakes...

Comment: I think these kind of questions are for increasing points/reputation as lot of people answers them. But many a times people do post useful information in the answers

Comment: @Indigo - there is a checkbox for a community wiki on the edit page. See the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The book [The ASP.Net 2.0 Anthology: 101 Essential Tips, Tricks & Hacks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098028581X) is good

[image]